# OSX and Safari Problems

Tags: html, css, wordpress, macos, safari

I am working with wordpress walkers and putting an icon just above the sub menu list items on primary navigation.

The problem is that with OSX. nothing I do via java or css positions the elements correctly in safari

http://thehaventucson.org/

I am more then willing to give creds to trustworthy peeps as well.

I would like to either get correct positioning or remove the element all together but on in safari.

I have combed through just about every snippet here and nothing seems to work.

Comment: and your input to my issue would be what? snark? whatever. and BTW its a safari specific css issue which is best looked at live anyways to understand what is happening. unless you in your infinite wisdom have pulled a matrix and can see without seeing. in either case, this is better then snippets of code which can't function outside their enviroment anyways....cough.....just saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using position: absolute instead of position: fixed on your little chip

Comment: ive been pushing it around with inspector and it seems to work. I had to rebuild this theme after the last guy and the only fix with the last theme was fixed. I didnt even think about switching that....excuse my tunnel vision and thanks man! big help